# if ($(window).width() < 768) {} not working when browser resizes. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to make it so that only when the browser is less than 768px, my navigation bar items will toggle hidden or shown when an element with "navlogo" is clicked. I know I'm not the most descriptive, but here's my code.

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {

    $(".navlogo").click( function (){
        $(".navwrapper").toggle();
    });
    $(".navitem").click( function (){
        $(".navwrapper").hide();
   });

}
```

I know this is actually going to get marked as a duplicate but it's not. The thing is that I want it to be able to even work without refreshing. If it requires Angular.js then it would be helpful to know what code to use for that because I wouldn't mind using it but yeah I just want for the user to not have to refresh every time to get the correct result.

Also, one bug that happens when I don't have the

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {}
```

is that yes it still works properly but even if the website is not in mobile mode, which occurs when the max width is 768px or lower, when the user clicks the element with "navlogo," it still hides the "navwrapper." That's not bad but the thing is that I also want it to hide when a user clicks on an element with "navitem."

Thank you!

Comment: Why would it work without a `resize` event handlers ?

Comment: Maybe take a look at CSS media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Yeah, resize handlers are the answer, but doing this in CSS looks like the much better way. No need for JS anymore here

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't believe you can do this in CSS. If you can, post an answer please, thank you :)

Comment: No, you're right, this exact thing can indeed not be done in CSS.

Comment: @KennethRhodes Consider a hybrid approach.  Make your basic setup with CSS media queries, and then either toggle a class, like `force-open` or something, or use the usual show/hide logic which will override the media query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The if statement should be inside the click function:

```
$(".navlogo").click( function (){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(".navwrapper").toggle();
    }
});
$(".navitem").click( function (){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(".navwrapper").hide();
    }
});
```

**Edit**:

To hide/show the .navwrapper when the window is resized you can listen to the window resize event.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {

    if ($(window).width() > 767 && $(".navwrapper").is(':hidden')) {
        $(".navwrapper").show();
    }

});
```

Some considerations:

- Try to use variables for selectors that will be called several times
- For efficiency try to enclose what happens in the [resize function in a timeout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/)
- Try to use CSS where possible for responsive instead of JavaScript

Comment: YES! This works 100% thank you! But is the only bug is that when resizing the window greater than 768px, if the user already had the navwrapper hidden, it's still hidden. Is there anyway I can force it to be unhidden when the page is resized above 768px?

Comment: Sure, in this case you need to add a resize function, let me include it in the answer.

Comment: Yep that worked perfectly, thank you! And yes I did use CSS for most things. Actually, here's a link to the full project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5rfnzqtjf4ci3f/Simple%20Navbar%201.0R1.zip?dl=0

(Ignore the readme.md, I published a video for friends on YouTube.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to try it only on desktop devices or both mobile and desktop devices.
In case, you want for both you can use two events:

"orientationChange" for mobile devices and
"resize" for desktop devices

Like,

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";
```

Now,

```
$(window).on(orientationEvent, function(evt){
   if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(".navlogo").click( function (){
        $(".navwrapper").toggle();
    });
    $(".navitem").click( function (){
        $(".navwrapper").hide();
   });
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Though, I am sticking with the answer by @Alvaro for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using .resize ()

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.width() < 768) {
        $(".navlogo").click( function (){
            $(".navwrapper").toggle();
        });
        $(".navitem").click( function (){
            $(".navwrapper").hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't work even after a refresh.

Comment: So run it twice - once inside the resize function, once onload. Whether the code runs off the bat or not, this is the piece you are missing.

Comment: Probably it works, but it works adding this code to your previous code. You need to run the "size checking process" two times, one when the pages load (this is the code that you already have), and other time when the browser changes their size (the code that Pablo posted).

Comment: Indeed, Alvaro's solution above is much more efficient. There's no need for `.resize()` after all.